# The background color changes when dragging the div

Tags: html, css, draggable

A div with draggable="true" will have a gradient effect after dragging the mouse. How do you keep it in its original color? This phenomenon only exists on Windows and not on Mac

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to change that. You'll have to implement the dragging yourself.

Comment: That is, your mac/windows tests reveal that the OS is doing what you dont desire on one of the operating systems.

Comment: @GetSet has nothing to do with the OS but rather the browsers or more specifically the rendering engine they use (e.g. Webkit, Chromium...). It is not normed or specified by W3C or WHATWG and as such Vendors are allowed to implement the defaults as they like.